# Twitter widget not embedding properly

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, widget

I am trying to embed a public twitter profile onto the frontpage of my website and I am having difficulty getting it to work. I went to twitter and created this"

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-theme="dark" data-link- 
color="#FAB81E" href="https://twitter.com/danacarlin3? 
ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by danacarlin3</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I tried to add this in to my html but all that shows up is a link to my twitter. All of the tutuorials I have watched have the entire feed sitting there. Am I forgetting to do something? I wanted to add this into an iframe but haven't even got that far because I Can't understand why it isn't showing up.

Dana

Comment: Hmm..seems to be working if you paste it in the body [link](https://codepen.io/SQuirreL4niner/pen/eMQZBR)

Comment: I dont know why it isn't.  No tweets are showing up. All I get is "Tweets by danacarlin3" and then nothing else. It is in my body too.

Comment: I just edited the link, it works now. Try *posting* all the rest of the HTML that the body goes in. Good luck!